# Finding partial derivatives of a 3 variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given the following function:

$q(k,l,m) = k\,p(k,l) + m^2$

where $(k,l,m) \in \mathbb{R}$; $p(k,l)$ is a differentible function of $k$ and $l$;$k$ and $l$ are differentiable functions of $m$

How do I find $\frac{\partial q}{\partial k}$,$\frac{\partial q}{\partial l}$,$\frac{\partial q}{\partial m}$?

My attempt is:

$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial k}= p(k,l) \times\begin{bmatrix}\frac{dk}{dm}+\frac{dl}{dm}\end{bmatrix} + p(k,l)\\
\frac{\partial q}{\partial l} = k\,p'_l(k,l)\,
\\\frac{\partial q}{\partial m} = 2m
$$

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: what? have you mixed up this? function is constant? and you are searching derivatives?

Comment: hello @cf16 i have made the important changes. i think this is the best i can express this question. perhaps you could edit the question to make it more solvable? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no problem, please see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial k}= 1p(k,l) + k \times\frac{\partial p}{\partial k}\\
\frac{\partial q}{\partial l}= k \times\frac{\partial p}{\partial l}\
\
\\\frac{\partial q}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial k}{\partial m}p(k,l) + k \times\frac{\partial p}{\partial m}+2m=\frac{\partial k}{\partial m}p(k,l)+k \times\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial p}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial m}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial l}\frac{\partial l}{\partial m}\end{bmatrix} + 2m\
$$

Comment: This has made a lot of things crystal clear. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, you are very welcome ; p